# How to unregister from c2dm?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

How to unregister from c2dm onclick button ?  I want to add to app feature to stop receive notifications when user sign out.

Comment: http://code.google.com/intl/pl-PL/android/c2dm/#unregistering

Answer (score 2):

To unregister from C2DM:

```
Intent unregIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER");
unregIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
startService(unregIntent);
```

From http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/#unregistering

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to inform your server to stop sending push messages to the mobile.

There is no need to unregister from C2DM servers because google already has a limit on messages sent to the servers. So, just inform your server to stop sending the messages.